# DNS client behaviour when one of the DNS servers refuses the query

Tags: dns, connection-refused

Suppose my OS has two DNS servers set, let say 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9. Is there some RFC that states what the DNS client should do if the first query performed has as answer the code 5 (refused)?

For example: if the query goes firstly to the IP 8.8.8.8, and it refused the query, what is the RFC recommendation for the client to do? To query the IP 9.9.9.9 or just accept the refused query as the final answer and throw an error to the application?

Comment: If the resolver gets a DNS reply, its job stops here. The list of nameservers in the OS is used only if the first one does not reply at all (a negative DNS reply is not the same thing as no reply). But your question is offtopic here.

Comment: If you look at a manual for `resolv.conf` for example you can read: "The algorithm used is to try a name server, and if the query times out, try the next, until out of name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers until a maximum number of retries are made." Of course other applications/OS can be more aggressive or less strict and do things differently but it won't then be in the spirit of the protocol. The best definition I can find is §6.1.3 of RFC 1123

Comment: But is there someplace in the RFC or elsewhere that says that the client should perform the way mentioned by you? "If the resolver gets a DNS replay, its job stops here".

Comment: It got a reply, why should it do anything else? Why I do not have the exact sentence from any source, you seem to be searching for a list of things NOT to do, so of course noone would attempt to do such lists. The protocol just says: you query a nameserver, you get a reply, you process it. And separately: if you got a timeout (no reply) then you kick it alternative options (retrying, switching to another nameserver, etc.). See also the quote from the `resolv.conf` manual.

Comment: The problem is more this: it got a reply "REFUSED" for example (or something else). Based on what criteria would it be able to say: "Nah, it expected something else, this answer is surely bogus, let me try something else..." Note that the strategy might be slightly different between the case of a stub resolver asking a full resolver and a full resolver asking authoritative nameservers. It is also obviously different between "day to day" normal resolutions and specific troubleshooting tools that will go deeper and query more.

Comment: It is good if it stops after getting REFUSED: it really means it (probably) shouldn't use that nameserver whatsoever (or at least the nameserver refuses to comply with the request). That should prompt the administrator of the box to fix the configuration and remove from the list the nameservers that shouldn't be queried.  Otherwise if it switches automatically to next in list, besides some small delay, noone will see there is a problem with the first nameserver...

Comment: Closer but not definitive is section 4 of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1536 (if we talk about stub resolver to full resolver, which is why I infer from your question)